# Printing characters to LCD - Verilog HDL

Tags: printing, ascii, verilog, lcd

I have a question regarding printing character to an LCD screen.

I am using an Altera DE1-SoC *5CSEMA5F31C6N* and a LT24 Terasic LCD.

I have a question regarding printing letters in a row on the LCD.

I am relying on the x and y counter to raster across the screen, starting at (0,0) upper left corner of the screen.
Incrementing x all the way to the end of the row, and once reached the end, reset x to 0, increment the y and then continue counting x again until the end of the screen

[LCD pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UgeH.png)

i am creating arrays to print character values (8x8 px)

The long array concatenates 'each row of pixels' for all characters, and then whilst the counter is rastered across the screen the pixels for each character will print to the lcd.

eg.
row0 - print first row of pixels for all characters.
row1 - print second row of pixels for all characters.

however, when i try to print 2 characters, the order of the characters being printed is reversed [from the origin (0,0)]

e.g. if i want to print 'I' then 'M'. I actually get 'M' and 'I' in that order.

when i try to print 3 characters, then no characters show at all!

I am really struggling to understand why this is the case, as the counter values are used to test the current bit of the character and then draw the pixel

Any help would be appreciated.

I have basic verilog understanding, but comfortable with c programming

Thank you,

code snippets are below.

```
////////////////////////////// code ////////////////////////////////////////////
reg [0] totalCharData [23:0];   //   pixel row0
reg [1] totalCharData [23:0];   //   pixel row1
reg [2] totalCharData [23:0];   //  pixel row2
reg [3] totalCharData [23:0];   //   pixel row3
reg [4] totalCharData [23:0];   //   
reg [5] totalCharData [23:0];   //   
reg [6] totalCharData [23:0];   //   
reg [7] totalCharData [23:0];   // pixel row 7

    // character  ‘I'
    totalCharData[7][7:0] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[6][7:0] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[5][7:0] = 8'b00111100;
    totalCharData[4][7:0] = 8'b00111100;
    totalCharData[3][7:0] = 8'b00111100;
    totalCharData[2][7:0] = 8'b00111100;
    totalCharData[1][7:0] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[0][7:0] = 8'b11111111;

    // character ‘M'
    totalCharData[7][15:8] = 8'b11100111;
    totalCharData[6][15:8] = 8'b11101111;
    totalCharData[5][15:8] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[4][15:8] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[3][15:8] = 8'b11010011;
    totalCharData[2][15:8] = 8'b11000011;
    totalCharData[1][15:8] = 8'b11000011;
    totalCharData[0][15:8] = 8'b11000011;

    // character ‘E'
    totalCharData[7][23:16] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[6][23:16] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[5][23:16] = 8'b11100000;
    totalCharData[4][23:16] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[3][23:16] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[2][23:16] = 8'b11100000;
    totalCharData[1][23:16] = 8'b11111111;
    totalCharData[0][23:16] = 8’b11111111;


// X Counter
always @ (posedge clock or posedge resetApp) begin
    if (resetApp) begin
        xAddr <= 8'b0;
    end else if (pixelReady) begin
        if (xAddr < (WIDTH-1)) begin
            xAddr <= xAddr + 8'd1;
        end else begin
            xAddr <= 8'b0;
        end
    end
end

// Y Counter
always @ (posedge clock or posedge resetApp) begin
    if (resetApp) begin
        yAddr <= 9'b0;
    end else if (pixelReady && (xAddr == (WIDTH-1))) begin
        if (yAddr < (HEIGHT-1)) begin
            yAddr <= yAddr + 9'd1;
        end else begin
            yAddr <= 9'b0;
        end
    end
end


// draw characters to the lcd
always @ (posedge clock or posedge resetApp) begin

   if (resetApp) begin
        pixelData[15:0] <=  16'h0000; ;     // wipe the full screen with background
   end else begin       // whilst bitton held, make blue

     if ((xAddr>=0) && (xAddr<24) && (yAddr>=0) && (yAddr<8))begin // draw complete row of pixels for all the characters in line
        if ((totalCharData[yAddr][xAddr] == 1'b1))begin  // test the current bit using the counters
                pixelData[15:0] <=  16'hFFE0; // yellow - draw pixel if the current bit is 1 as defined
        end
        else begin
            pixelData[15:0] <=  16'h0000; 
        end // else 
     end else begin
        pixelData[15:0] <=  16'h0000;   // black screen
     end

   end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at how you initially define your registers.  Based on how you are accessing them in your RTL, I expected them be defined as

```
reg [23:0] total_char_data [0:7]
```

This does in one line what you were trying to do in 8, BUT notice that the [23:0] is on the left side (packed array) and the [0:7] is on the right (unpacked array) in my definition.  When done like this, I think your existing assignments work.

Based on this though, I don't know how you are even getting two characters to show up.  I would have imagined just looking at it, that only one character would appear, within the 8x8 window.   I don't suppose you have any interesting WARNINGS in your compile that say things like, "outside of bit range"?